# System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem C# Error

Tags: c#, listview

> for (indx = 0; (indx <= (Dt.Rows.Count - 1)); indx++)
>
> ```
>         {
>             ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
>             lv.Text = Dt.Rows[indx]["ID"];
>             lv.SubItems.Add(Dt.Rows[indx]["GuestFName"]);
>             lvGuest.Items.Add(lv);
>         }
> ```

So this is my problem. I got squiggly lines under

> lv.SubItems.Add(Dt.Rows[indx]["GuestFName"]);

The error says

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection.Add (System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem)' has some invalid arguments

What seems to be the problem? :(

Answer (score 3):

[ListViewSubItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitemcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class has two `Add` methods - one accepts `string` another one accepts `ListViewSubItem` instance. I think you should use first one in this case - just convert row field value to string:

```
lv.SubItems.Add(Dt.Rows[indx]["GuestFName"].ToString());
```

NOTE: You can use LINQ to DataTable here:

```
foreach(var row in Dt.AsEnumerable())
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text = row.Field<string>("ID");
    item.SubItems.Add(row.Field<string>("GuestFName"));
    lvGuest.Items.Add(item);    
}
```

Comment: Hey there sir Sergey! Thanks for the reply. I'll give this a shot and see if it works.